# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, email

Web application give error after sending few mails:
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved
When I send mail from my C#.Net code. 
My application hosted on cloud server and this error raise after some time, when I restart application pool it work again.

public void SendMail(string ToEmailID, string CCEmailID, string Subject, string Body, System.Collections.ArrayList _Attachments = null)
            MailMessage mm = null;
            SmtpClient smtp = null;

```
        try
        {
            string strPath = "";
            string strReplacepath = "";

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request != null)
            {
                strPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
                strReplacepath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
                strPath = strPath.Replace(strReplacepath, "/");
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"]))
            {
                strPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"];
            }

            Body = Body.Replace("@@LOGO@@", GetImage(strPath, "Content/images/logo.jpg"));
            Body = Body.ToString().Replace("@@Year@@", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

            mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.Subject = Subject;
            mm.Body = Body;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mm.To.Add(ToEmailID);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CCEmailID))
                mm.CC.Add(CCEmailID);

            mm.Bcc.Add("My Email Address");

            if (_Attachments != null && _Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _Attachments.Count; i++)
                {
                    mm.Attachments.Add((Attachment)_Attachments[i]);
                }
            }
            smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Timeout = 25000;

            smtp.Send(mm);

        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (Attachment attachment in mm.Attachments)
            {
                attachment.Dispose();
            }

            if (_Attachments != null)
                _Attachments.Clear();

            if (mm != null)
                mm.Dispose();

            if (smtp != null)
                smtp.Dispose();

            mm = null;
            smtp = null;
            _Attachments = null;

        }
```

}

I have used smtp.gmail.com and port is 587 used.

Comment: DNS error? Anyway just [wait and retry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25014282/1207195).

Comment: what you tried? did u debugged the code ?

Comment: Hi Chris I have added my mail sending function code.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, I have check my application in local IIS and then deploy my code to server recycle app pool and test, It working for some time and stop sending mail after some time. and No I am not able to debuge my code on server.