# The remote name could not be resolved when sending mail using SMTP with Host as IP address

Tags: c#, .net, windows, smtpclient

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Subject = "test";
message.Body = "test";
message.To.Add("test@gmail.com");
message.From = new MailAddress("bob@internalhost.com");
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Host = "172.22.0.20";
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Any idea why I might be getting an error

> The remote name could not be resolved.

Clearly no resolution is required as I have specified an IP address. I can ping the IP and even telnet on port 25 and successfully send an e-mail. But, I can't send an e-mail.

I ran a `wireshark` trace and it doesn't look like any traffic is being send to 172.22.0.20

Comment: add and check if it works with either true or false `smtp.EnableSsl = false`

Comment: also you need to add `NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(EmailFrom, tEmailFromPassword);`

Comment: @RahulHendawe our internal smtp server doesn't require authentication

Comment: @RahulHendawe adding `smtp.EnableSsl = false` didn't help either

Comment: Try set empty credentials: smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();

Comment: Could u indicate what OS and what language?

Comment: @dgoo2308 windows server 2008 r2 standard, c#

Comment: @klashar frustratingly this seems to have magically started working, but would you be able to explain why your suggest may help? and why I would receive this misleading error?

Comment: Assume there's no proxy involved as well locally to connect to the web?

Comment: @Paul i don't believe so (i can telnet to that ip on port 25 without problem)

Comment: Do you have an exact error/stack trace?

Comment: @LeeTickett, You have quite unique setup with anonymous access to SMTP server. Even though you have specified `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false`. It would attempt setup the credentials to access the SMTP. With `smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()` you explicitly say that request will go anonymously. I guess in your case [smtpconnection](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/smtpconnection.cs,cbed1f9671320cdf,references) goes in via wrong path and you are getting misleading error message.

Comment: @SimonMourier unfortunately it magically started working so I can't provide a stack trace now. I think I will have to just re-raise if it happens again.

Comment: Maybe a red-herring but smpt host is a string and you're assigning it a number: `smtp.Host = 172.22.0.20;` - not sure how you got that to compile, if the problem happens again please include the complete code and Error Message/StackTrace.

Comment: If you are doing this at work, are you behind a network firewall? Could the firewall or antivirus be causing the issue? You might want to try talking to your system admin about this. You could also try running the code at home with your home computer. If it still does not work, then disable your antivirus software (temporarily) and try again.

Comment: @BobBryan sounds likely, but it's the fact that telnet works fine and also the misleading error that confuses me

Comment: @JeremyThompson good spot, but you're right, it's a red herring as my actual code pulls the IP from the app.config. I just replaced that with the IP for SO benefit.

Comment: Is there a system level proxy configured for .net possibly? What happens if you try a webrequest?

Comment: The other issue could be that your ISP is blocking traffic on port 25. Some ISP's require you to open that port on your account

Answer (score 8):

I use this code and its working fine on my end
Make sure that you are using the correct IP Address and port number. I think your Port Number is not correct.
(open your email id and check mail configuration)

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("bob@internalhost.com", "Toemai@email.com");
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = "this is email body";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("172.22.0.20");
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("bob@internalhost.com", "password");
client.Port = 25;

client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code with :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.Subject = "test";
                message.Body = "test";
                message.To.Add("atmane.elbouachri@gmail.com");
                message.From = new MailAddress("atmane.elbouachri@softeam.fr");
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Host = "127.0.0.1";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

And it seems good. I used smtp4dev Tools and it truks this :

```
220 localhost smtp4dev ready
EHLO Aepro
250-Nice to meet you.
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS
250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS
250 SIZE
MAIL FROM:<atmane.elbouachri@softeam.fr>
250 Okey dokey
RCPT TO:<atmane.elbouachri@gmail.com>
250 Recipient accepted
RSET
250 Rset completed
RSET
250 Rset completed
MAIL FROM:<atmane.elbouachri@softeam.fr>
250 Okey dokey
RCPT TO:<atmane.elbouachri@gmail.com>
250 Recipient accepted
DATA
354 End message with period
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

But when i put a fake IP I have an exception (witch is normal).

I think your IP is bad or you must have a problem with a firewall

Answer (score 3):

Below code is working fine at my end.....

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("abc@xyz.in", "receiver@xyz.in");
mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
mailMessage.Body = "message";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("host/IP", 25);
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@xyz.in", "password");
smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code is running in a service application pool - you need to set the Identity under Advanced Settings in the Process Model as "Network Service" rather than the default "ApplicationPoolIdentity". If you do that, it'll work every time. If you don't, some emails work, some do not. It is a weird permission thing.

Comment: I experienced this problem a few days ago using log4net smtp appender. Some emails worked. Some didn't. I was totally freaked out. But lo and behold, I found a similar problem on StackOverflow that provided the solution (as outlined above) and it worked perfectly. I share with you now.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue popped up over here: [System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014110/system-net-webexception-the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved)

As you can see, a simple polling mechanism wrapped around a try-catch statement can gives you an opportunity try your block of method multiple times (which fails sporadically) before you report it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is this line:

```
smtp.Host = 172.22.0.20;
```

smtp.Host expects string. So, it should be `smtp.Host = "172.22.0.20";` Besides that, please add the code below so we can see error

```
try 
{
    smtp.Send(mail); 
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: that's my mistake... the code is actually pulling the IP from the app.config. I replaced it with the IP when I copied/pasted to SO. unfortunately this is not the issue. the e.Message is `the remote name could not be resolved`

Comment: @LeeTickett, no problem! if you pulling it from web.config please paste the web.config for the host and port. It should be something like below and your delivery method should be smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis: 
 <system.net >
    <mailSettings >
      <smtp deliveryMethod="whateverYouNamed" >
        <network host ="172.22.0.20" port ="25" defaultCredentials ="true "/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>

Answer (score 0):

Your IP address is not correct or you might be working under a firewall. Also check you DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reverse name is mandatory, have you tried to register a name for this IP in the host file ? (Or in your DNS of course)

Try to add:

```
172.22.0.20 my-smtp.example
```