# Azure WCF Service is reachable with WcfTestClient, but not through the browser or MVC site

Tags: azure, wcf, wcftestclient

I have a WCF Service hosted on Azure.  I can reach the service with WcfTestClient, but when I open the *.svc file in the browser it says "Server Not Found" and when I use the service from an MVC site it says "There was no endpoint listening at (url) that could accept the message".  Both WcfTestClient and the MVC site are using BasicHttpBinding.

What does WcfTestClient do differently?

Comment: Today, the browser is able to reach the svc and wsdl pages.  I'm comparing the three lookup methods in Fiddler.  The mvc site is complaining that the DNS lookup failed.

Comment: The DNS lookup failure was only because I have Fiddler open while running the site locally.  I'm back to the System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at (url) that could accept the message.  Inner exception System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014110/system-net-webexception-the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: WcfTestClient is a GUI tool that enables users to input test parameters, submit that input to the service, and view the response that the service sends back. It provides a seamless service testing experience when combined with WCF Service Host. If other applications need to call WCF services, they need to generate proxy classes based on WSDL documents to call WCF services.

Comment: WcfTestClient is nothing special, it is also a client.

Comment: Once I added domain names to the Azure service and site, the site was able to access the service.  So that's working now.  But I still don't understand why the WcfTestClient could access the service at the default Azure url when the site couldn't.

Comment: I suspect it may be caused by the network failure.