# IDbConnection Open hangs C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

My program execution hangs on .Open() method longer than specified 2 seconds timeout when connecting to SQL-Server.

I managed to reproduce the problem when machine that database is on is offline or restartig. When machine that database is on get up the execution of program un-hangs.

How can I force to throw exception or whatever when 2 second timeout exceed?

I tried OleDB and SqlConnection provider, no difference.

I can ping the machine before connecting to it but there is still case that ping will be successful (let's say 1 second before machine shutdown) and then Open connection hangs...

Example code provided below.

```
public static IDbConnection GetConnection(IDbConnection connection)
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "connectionString; Connection Timeout=2;";
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Connection Timeout property is just the time for the connection to be created, everything after that (and there is a lot to do after connection is established) does not _count_ and it may take indefinitely (unless there is _another_ timeout I'm not aware of). What you can do is to execute your own code in a separate thread with a _watchdog_ to limit total time execution to 2 seconds (be careful that for a TCP connection 2 seconds are a very short time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection Timeout` property is just the time for the connection to be created, everything after that (and there is a lot to do after connection is established) does not *count* and it may take indefinitely (unless there is *another* timeout I'm not aware of).

What you can do is to execute your own code in a separate thread with a watchdog to limit total time execution to two seconds. Using tasks it is pretty easy:

```
const int HardConnectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = 2000;
if (!Task.Run(() => connection.Open()).Wait(HardConnectionTimeoutInMilliseconds))
    return null; // Timeout!
```

Just for completeness this is *old-style code* for this:

```
Thread worker = new Thread(delegate()
{
    connection.Open();
});
worker.Start();

if (!worker.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
     return null;
```

**Be careful** with so short timeout: for a TCP connection two seconds are always a too short time and if you're using Windows authentication with AD then it may takes longer than you expect.

In my opinion you have to *live* with this lag (15 to 30 seconds are a safe and reasonable time for TCP connection with integrated security). You may also want to wait more and retry (because errors may be temporary, see [Know when to retry or fail when calling SQL Server from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24041062/1207195)), note that situation you're describing (server is *going down*) is pretty unusual then IMO it shouldn't affect normal operations. If it's an issue for your UI then you should make your program parallel (to keep UI responsive).