# Automatically retry request on SqlException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have to modify my static class used to process my SQL calls in order to retry the request if there is some specific `SqlException` (connection lost for example).

Here is my method used to call a stored procedure:

```
public static int CallExecuteNonQuery(string storedProcName, Action<SqlCommand> fillParamsAction, Action afterExecution, BDDSource source)
{
    int result;

    try
    {
        using (var connection = InitSqlConnection(source))

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, connection))
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (fillParamsAction != null)
                fillParamsAction(command);

            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (afterExecution != null)
                afterExecution();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlExn)
    {
        Logger.Exception(string.Format("SQL CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), sqlExn);
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Exception(string.Format("SOFTWARE CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), exception);
        throw;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041062/know-when-to-retry-or-fail-when-calling-sql-server-from-c), I'm trying to retry the request as many time as it's configured for.

I got the following code:

```
public static int CallExecuteNonQuery(string storedProcName, Action<SqlCommand> fillParamsAction, Action afterExecution, BDDSource source)
{
    bool RetryRequest = true;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Settings.Default.Request_MaximumRetry; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (RetryRequest)
            {
                using (var connection = InitSqlConnection(source))
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, connection))
                {
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    if (fillParamsAction != null)
                        fillParamsAction(command);

                    result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (afterExecution != null)
                        afterExecution();
                }

                RetryRequest = false;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlExn)
        {
            if (sqlExn.Errors.Cast<SqlError>().All(x => (x.Class >= 16 && x.Class < 22) || x.Class == 24))
            {
                RetryRequest = true;
                continue;
            }

            Logger.Exception(string.Format("SQL CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), sqlExn);
            RetryRequest = false;
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Exception(string.Format("SOFTWARE CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), exception);
            RetryRequest = false;
            throw;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But my modifications are not perfect. For example, after 3 retry with exception, the code doesn't throw and goes into the `continue;` section before going out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you're aware of the caveats of automatic retries, especially when these concern non-idempotent operations.

Rather than using local variables for keeping track of success or failure, I would suggest using control flow keywords directly for this purpose:

```
public static int CallExecuteNonQuery(string storedProcName, Action<SqlCommand> fillParamsAction, Action afterExecution, BDDSource source)
{
    int retryCount = 0;   // recoverable exception will be rethrown 
                          // when this count reaches limit

    while (true)   // conditions for breaking out of loop inlined
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = InitSqlConnection(source))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, connection))
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (fillParamsAction != null)
                    fillParamsAction(command);
                var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (afterExecution != null)
                    afterExecution();
                return result;   // on success, return immediately
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlExn)
        {
            // if error is recoverable, and retry count has not exceeded limit,
            // then retry operation
            if (sqlExn.Errors.Cast<SqlError>().All(x => (x.Class >= 16 && x.Class < 22) || x.Class == 24)
                && ++retryCount < Properties.Settings.Default.Request_MaximumRetry)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // otherwise, rethrow exception
            Logger.Exception(string.Format("SQL CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), sqlExn);
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Exception(string.Format("SOFTWARE CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), exception);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a "RetryPolicy" class for this purpose.

**The class:**

```
public struct RetryPolicy<T>
{
    private int mRetryMax;
    private int mRetryWaitSec;

    public RetryPolicy(int retryMax, int retryWaitSec)
    {
        mRetryMax = retryMax;
        mRetryWaitSec = retryWaitSec;
    }

    public T DoWork(System.Func<T> func)
    {
        int retries = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch when (++retries < RetryMax)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(RetryWaitSec * 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public int RetryMax
    {
        get
        {
            return mRetryMax;
        }
    }

    public int RetryWaitSec
    {
        get
        {
            return mRetryWaitSec;
        }

        set
        {
            mRetryWaitSec = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
new RetryPolicy<int>(int.MaxValue, 1000).DoWork(() =>
{
  Connect(); return 0;
});
```

This way you can have one line client code that retries a number of times with a millisecond interval.

You could adjust it to a generic for just catching SQLException or whatever you want. Right now it catches all exceptions.

It's non static so you can cache the RetryPolicy during startup.

```
RetryPolicy policy = new RetryPolicy<int>(int.MaxValue, 1000);
// later
policy.DoWork(() => { Connect(); return 0; });
```

Comment: That's a clever use of `when`, although I'm not certain that it's safe to have side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems utterly complex, also I'd take advantage of `AggregatedException` class to report all recoverable failures.

```
public static int CallExecuteNonQuery(string storedProcName, Action<SqlCommand> fillParamsAction, Action afterExecution, BDDSource source)
{
    int result = 0;
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = InitSqlConnection(source))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, connection))
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (fillParamsAction != null)
                    fillParamsAction(command);
                result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (afterExecution != null)
                    afterExecution();
            }
            break;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlExn)
        {
            if (sqlExn.Errors.Cast<SqlError>().All(x => (x.Class >= 16 && x.Class < 22) || x.Class == 24))
            {
                exceptions.Add(sqlExn);
                if (exceptions.Count == Properties.Settings.Default.Request_MaximumRetry)
                {
                    throw new AggregateException("Too many attempts.", exceptions);
                }
                continue;
            }

            Logger.Exception(string.Format("SQL CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), sqlExn);
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Exception(string.Format("SOFTWARE CRITICAL ERROR. Stored Proc Name : {0}", storedProcName), exception);
            throw;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```